# Cannot hook into another RxSwift stream based on a check

Tags: swift, io, rx-swift

Cannot hook into another RxSwift Stream based on the check that was added before the network request.

I am constructing a UserProfile object but I want to make sure that the userProfile object has been completely created. I have a stream that is creating the userProfile object but now I have a check. I want to hook into the previous stream so that upon a complete UserProfile I can perform a network request. I'm unsure about how to hook into the previous stream. The updateUserProfile($0) is where I am passing the UserProfile object to make the network request but I want to make sure that I stop right there.

```
let userInfoResponse = latestLocallySavedUserProfileDictionary
            .map { (dictionary: [String: String?]) in
               return UserProfile(
                    firstName: dictionary["firstName"] ?? "",
                    lastName: dictionary["lastName"] ?? "",
                    phone: dictionary["phone"] ?? "",
                    company: dictionary["company"] ?? "",
                    organizationType: dictionary["organizationType"] ?? "",
                    jobFunction: dictionary["jobFunction"] ?? "",
                    addressLine1: dictionary["addressLine1"] ?? "",
                    addressLine2: dictionary["addressLine2"] ?? "",
                    city: dictionary["city"] ?? "",
                    state: dictionary["state"] ?? nil,
                    zipCode: dictionary["zipCode"] ?? "",
                    country: dictionary["country"] ??  "",
                    languageCode: dictionary["languageCode"] ?? "",
                    merrillDisclaimerAccepted: false, // ignore for now
                    merrillDisclaimerAcceptedDate: "" // ignore for now
                )
            }

            .flatMapLatest { updateUserProfile($0) }
            .share()

        isUserProfileDictionaryComplete = Observable.merge([
            initialUserProfileCall,
            userInfoResponse
                .map{$0.createDictionary()},
            userProfileLocal
            ])
                .asObservable()
                .map{(profileDictionary) -> Bool in
                    return profileDictionary.values.contains(nil) || profileDictionary.values.contains("")
                }
                .ignore(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do, but in general you need to figure out all the events that should prompt a network request and put them in the stream before the flatMapLatest.

If you are trying to build up a `UserProfile` from your `latestLocallySavedUserProfileDictionary`, `initialUserProfileCall`, and `userProfileLocal` then you might want to put a scan after the merge to collect all the bits from each dictionary.